# Rails 3: client_side_validations gem and devise password validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, client-side-validation

I've got the client_side_validations gem working really great on my forms. I'm using Devise for my users model and when I go to the edit_user_registration form, validations are thrown up for everything except the :current_password, :password, and :password_confirmation fields.

Fort instance is I leave the email blank, the validation pops up right when I tab out of the field. However, if I leave the current_password field blank and tab out of it nothing happen, then when I submit the form I get the error "1 error prohibited this user from being saved: password can't be blank"

Thanks for any help

http://pastie.org/1907464

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Currently ClientSideValidations will filter out any conditional validators. Devise sets some of the validators as conditional: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/validatable.rb#L24-32

The reason I did this is because there is no good way for the client to determine the true value of that conditional. I could do it at the time the form is generated but what if that conditional relied upon a value that could be changed on the form? So I opted to filter them and let things fall back to the server.

That was the idea but clearly it has imposed unfair limitations on some things. This being the most obvious (and popular).

So I plan on releasing a new version very soon that will allow you to explicitly override the conditional filters. It will work like this:

```
<%= f.text_field :password, :validate => { :presence => true, :confirmation => true } %>
```

or

```
<%= f.text_field :password, :validate => true %>
```

In the first case you can choose which validators to turn the filter off. In the 2nd case it will turn the filter off for all validators on that attribute. The conditional will be evaluated at the time the form is generated and if it passes it will add the validator to the input element for use on the client.

Comment: I did try recently to use your suggested approach, sadly it didn't work. I ended up adding this to my model: `if we_need_to_validate_some_more; validates_presence_of :not_always_important_field; end`. Works like a charm on server side and it gets picked up by your gem.

Comment: this comment was from over a year ago, it is most likely no longer valid

Answer (score 4):

The master branch now supports this format. Point your Gemfile to it and you should be good

Comment: Thanks a lot I have it working now. Side note: is there a way to display a notice for when a validation passes? So I could style it up with red for failure and green for success?

Comment: You'll want to use the callbacks for that. https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations/wiki/Callbacks

Comment: Hi, I've noticed that the client_side_validations are only called on <%= f.password_field :password %> and not on <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>. So if I tab out of the password_confirmation field nothing is shown. Is there a way to get a validation for password and password_confirmation to match? Or at least a presence validation for password_confirmation?

Comment: I added "validates :password_confirmation, :presence => true" which works for the presence validation, but I can't seem to get a validation for matching passwords. Is this possible? Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: @trying_hal9000 no, the validation itself is on the 'password' attribute. Not the 'password_confirmation' attribute.

Comment: FYI, I have a patch pushed for Rails 4.0 which will make this less confusing. The validation error will rende on the confirmation field instead of the password field now. This has been a Rails issue all along, work arounds are pretty fragile

Answer (score 0):

It’s simple! The gem extends the Rails default form builder, and all you have to do is set a :validate => true option on any form_for (or simple_form_for for simple form users) tag that you want the inline validations for. The form builder uses some rails reflections on your model validations to generate some json that gets included in a script tag after your form. The json is then used by the gem’s Javascript framework to perform the validations that need to be performed.

```
<%= form_for(@user, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :validate => true) do |f| %>
```