# client_side_validations gem password field devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, devise, client-side-validation

I'm trying to setup client_side_validations for the password field in devise. One of my validations is presence of a password. The problem is in the edit form, the :password field is for the new password, which I want to allow to be blank in the case when the user is not trying to change his password.

I set up my own validations in the user model so that I could use the client_side_validations in the sign_up form. But they're interfering with the edit form.

Any suggestions on how I should proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try setting your Gemfile to pull from the master branch on Github and try the format noted here:

[Rails 3: client_side_validations gem and devise password validations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6012428/rails-3-client-side-validations-gem-and-devise-password-validations/6040520#6040520)

And let me know if the issue still exists?

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm really new at this. How do I do that?

Comment: gem 'client_side_validations', :git => 'git://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations.git'